# An alternative to a fingerprint scanner to directly store registrations online

Tags: fingerprint-scanner

We are currently recording our student attendance manually on paper and feeding it on the system at a later time.

The problems are many
1. Slow to search for the student on paper - although it's grouped class wise and we have 200 students only. It causes errors many a times too.
2. Tasking to match paper records to system every time
3. We want to send SMS immediately to parents if the student is absent
4. The system is currently offline but we want to store it on a website now. We can continue the same process but of uploading it online now.

We are thinking of using a biometric fingerprint device to solve 1. I.e. speed up and avoid errors. We would export the data and store it online.

My concern is that the process of uploading is manual and I have a tingling feeling that something can go wrong. We have to upload the records then the SMS alerts can go. So if we delay uploading, the SMS concept will be unworthy.

I wished to give students cards with a barcode which would be scanned. This way speed is increased and errors are minimised like for a biometric fingerprint scanner.

The issue with this is that our students can often forget their cards unlike their fingerprints :)

We don't have a device here that works with auto records uploading in my city unfortunately.

Can you suggest a way (s) that can allow attendance recording to an online system with the same benefits as above?

Comment: This isn't strictly a hardware request. Are you looking for a barcode scanner, biometric scanner, combination, etc? "Something could go wrong" - Yeah. You could have an insecure server on your network on then all the biometric data will be vulnerable. Policy-wise, I'd go with the barcode reader (not an RFID reader). Build a policy around forgotten ID cards. Make it painful for the students so they don't forget again. Have *them* fill out the attendance paperwork, make them go to the office to get a temporary ID, etc. Something that costs them time and effort. It's inconvenient for the day.

Comment: My personal suggestion was for the barcode reader. Also like the idea to task the student so that he doesn't forget. I'll present this.